# Django Contact Form POST. 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: post, django-forms, contact-form, http-status-code-405

I hope this text finds you well.
I'm experiencing an issue in my django project (code) and I'm in need of your help.

When I filled the form and clicked the submit button, I expect to be directed to the success page, but I keep getting "Method Not Allowed (POST):/success/" in my terminal and "This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405" display on my screen (browser).

Thanks.

Here's my Contact Form HTML code:

```
 <form class="p-6 flex flex-col justify-center bg-gray_like rounded-lg" 
method="POST" action="{% url 'base:success' %}"> {% csrf_token %}
 
<div class="flex flex-col">
  <label for="name" class="hidden">Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" 
   class="w-100 mt-2 py-3 px-3 rounded-lg bg-white border border-blue text-black font-md    focus:border-blue focus:outline-none"></div>
                                    
<div class="flex flex-col mt-2">
   <label for="email" class="hidden">Email</label>
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="w-100 mt-2 py-3 px-3  rounded-lg bg-white 0 border border-blue text-black font-md focus:border-blue focus:outline-none"></div>

<div class="flex flex-col mt-2">
  <label for="subject" class="hidden">Subject</label>
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" 
class="w-100 mt-2 py-3 px-3 rounded-lg bg-white border border-blue text-black font-md focus:border-blue focus:outline-none"></div>
 
<div class="flex flex-col mt-2">
  <label for="message" class="hidden">Message</label>
 <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" 
class="w-100 mt-2 py-3 px-3 rounded-lg bg-white border border-blue text-black font-md focus:border-blue focus:outline-none"></textarea></div>
<button type="submit" class="md:w-35 bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark text-white font-bold py-3 px-10 rounded-lg mt-3 hover:bg-indigo-500 transition ease-in-out duration-300">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

Here's my veiw.py

```
#Contact Form view

class ContactView(FormView):
 
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            
            if form.is_valid(): #Form validation

            #extract data from the form
                name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
                message = form.cleaned_data['message']

               # send email to recipient
                send_mail(
                    'CONTACT FORM SUBMITTED',
                    f'Name: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nSubject: {subject}\nMessage: {message}',
                    'sender@email.com',
                   ['recipient1@email.com','recipient2@email.com'],
                    fail_silently= False)
               
                return render(request,'/success.html')
            else:
                form = ContactForm()
            return render(request,'contact.html/',{'form':form})
```

Here's my base app url code:

```
app_name = 'base'

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
   path('services/', views.ServicesPageView.as_view(), name='services'),
   path('about_us/', views.About_UsPageView.as_view(), name='about_us'),
   path('price/', views.PricePageView.as_view(), name='price'),
   path('portfolio/', views.PortfolioPageView.as_view(), name='portfolio'),
   path("<int:pk>/", views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='project_detail'),
   path('contact', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
   path('success/', views.SuccessPageView.as_view(), name='success'),

]
```

Error Message in the Terminal :

"Method Not Allowed (POST): /success/
Method Not Allowed: /success/
[22/Aug/2023 05:59:19] "POST /success/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0"